# JQuery search no longer working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post, freebase

I cannot figure out why this isn't working.  It's a JQuery search box that uses the Freebase API to find games.  When I POST, the gameID and gameName are blank.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://freebaselibs.com/static/suggest/1.3/suggest.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://freebaselibs.com/static/suggest/1.3/suggest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $("#game-search").suggest({type:'/games/game'}).bind("fbSelect", function(e, data) {
        $("#game-id").val(data.id);
        $("#game-name").val(data.name);
        });
      });
</script>


<form name="input" action="/game-profile" method="post">
  <input class="search-box" name="fbSelect" type="text" id="game-search"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="gameID" id="game-id" />
  <input type="hidden" name="gameName" id="game-name" />
  <input class="button" value="Go" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the fbSelect event you're binding to, ever gets fired. Have you included all required code parts for this to work?

Comment: Dean - that's it!  I've got a typo there, it should be 'fb-select'  That was an HOUR of pain.  Post the answer and I'll score you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I grabbed your code and changed the hidden fields to `type="text"` just so I could see the data when a selection was made from the auto-complete.  The fields weren't being populated on select, so I took a quick peek at the API.

It looks like the event you should be binding to is `fb-select` rather than `fbSelect` a la:

```
  $(function() {
    $("#game-search").suggest({type:'/games/game'}).bind("fb-select", function(e, data) {
    $("#game-id").val(data.id);
    $("#game-name").val(data.name);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like the fbSelect event you're binding to, ever gets fired. Have you included all required code parts for this to work?

(Answered retrospectively via comment on original question. @borkweb is more correct.)